# QRegExpValidator parameters

Tags: c++, qt, qregexp

If I write the following:

```
QValidator *validator = new QRegExpValidator(regExp, this);
```

What does `this` mean here? What is it referring to? If I don't use it what effect will occur?

Comment: please read a good C++ book. (this site has a FAQ if you click on the C++ tag with [lots of information](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info) ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a pointer to the current class where `validator` is declared in.

its there to let QRegExpValidator know who is the parent of `validator` so whenever the parent is deleted, so as `validator`. this way you dont need to delete it manually.

More about the `this` pointer, see [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/cplr035.htm)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So, can we say that the main reasons of having `this` is: *determine the parent* and *avoiding manual deletion of validator*?

Comment: @user58855: Yes, or rather to enable automatic garbage collection when the parent is deleted.